Configuring tls termination for traefik ingress on localhost
So I have been reading the documentation for traefik ingress over and over again, but I cannot seem to grasp how I add tls termination on localhost with a self-signed certificate.
I have the following kubernetes configuraitions:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: secret-tls
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: |
    LS0tL...
  tls.key: |
    LS0tLS1CR...

And for the ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nextjs-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-https-redirect@kubernetescrd
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    namespace: default
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: secret-tls
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: my-service
                port:
                  number: 80

---
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: https-redirect
  namespace: default
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    permanent: true
    scheme: https
    # port: "443"

According to the documentation, I suppose this should be correct. But when I make a request to my ingress, I get a 404.
I am running this in k3s - hence also why I figured going with the pre-installed traefik ingress would be a good start.
Using Let's Encrypt seems like a breeze and I would perhaps configure that opposed to a self-signed certificate once I do an actual deployment - But for now, I am learning how to do this locally.
So to summarize, I think I have the following questions (apart from how i get it to work):

How does the Ingress resource know to read the tls.crt and tls.key from the secret, nowhere in the documentation does it say that it should be specified as a data object
Do I need to setup local DNS for this to work?

